# Unable to find variable `flex` in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am not able to use variable `flex` while styling. I expected it to work because it is included in `StyleSheet`.

[image]

Comment: Try to add your code. People can't understand your problem just from that image

Comment: Yes, we need your code. Try to post your code on https://snack.expo.io/ at least. That would help a lot.

Comment: try to share your code or just a snippet of it, must be a typo or the way you write style.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. I found out the error,it was because I didn't write it according to their required style. From next time,I will keep your suggestions in mind while asking a question. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use flex similar to CSS. When writing styling in React Native, you have to write quotation marks before. So like this:

`display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I found out the error,it was because I didn't write it according to their required style..

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you tried, {flex,...anotherProp},.. with new EcmaScript's you can assign a prop just by

```
let flex = 1
//and
let myObj = {flex} //outs=> {flex: 1} // the thing is that you might be writing wrong the props of your object, and or missing ","
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I found out the error,it was because I didn't write it according to their required style..